# Изменение класса в другом блоке

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как через JQuery сделать так, чтобы при клике на ссылку `id="item01`" сменился класс у блока `id="itemText01"`. Номера у них всех соответствуют друг другу: `item01 = itemText01`, `item123 = itemText123`.
Нужно для того, чтобы при клике на текст в блок помощи показывался привязанный к этой ссылке текст.

Спасибо.

**Обновление**

Нет. Не работает. Вот пытаюсь с этим что-то сделать. Где-то ошибся...

```
$('.item').live('click', function(e) {
    var id_click = e.target.id;
        $('#info-block').find('.itemText' + e.target.id.substr(4, e.target.id.lenght)).addClass('active');

    });
```

Comment: Не проще ли для этой цели дата-атрибут попользовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мда. itemText у меня не класс, а id (# забыл).

Возможно, кому-то пригодится. Ответ на поставленную мною задачу:

```
$('.item').live('click', function(e) {
    var id_click = e.target.id;
    $('#info-block').find('#textItem' + e.target.id.substr(4, e.target.id.lenght)).addClass('active');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#item01").click(function(){ $("#itemText"+$(this).attr("id").replace("item","")).addClass() }`

Comment: Обновил вопрос